# Web Scraping Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scraping

preciso fazer um código que identifique sempre o nome do vendedor do produto nessa página

https://www.netshoes.com.br/tenis-asics-japan-s-i-masculino-branco+preto-2FW-1718-028?campaign=gglepqpla&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAjwh4-wBhB3EiwAeJsppJvKJoa3tF2ssBC1LbPkKFlV4O_7zu0vtew2p38TPZpjJeRd6ltIPhoCQcIQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds

o problema é que a cada variação de numeração o nome do vendedor pode mudar e eu não consigo identificar no html o que determina essa mudança, alguém consegue me ajudar?